# Finding strong numbers between 1-500?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm stuck here. This program stops after giving 1 and 2 strong numbers just and doesn't do anything afterwards[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vPCe.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int fac=1,rem=0,strong_num=0,store=0,loop=1;

    cout<<"The strong numbers in the range 1 - 500 are give below\n";
    while(1<=loop<=500)
    {

        store=loop;
        while(loop>0)
        {
            rem=loop%10;
            while(rem>0)
            {
                fac=fac*rem;
                rem--;
            }
            strong_num=strong_num+fac;
            loop=loop/10;
        }
        loop=store;
        if(strong_num==loop)
        {
            cout<<loop<<endl;
        }
        strong_num=0;
        loop++;
        fac=1;
    }
}
```

I know i have made a blunder but dont know how to resolve it ?
help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first while loop.

```
while(1<=loop<=500)
```

To

```
while(1<=loop && loop<=500)
```

Change second while loop.

```
while(loop>0)
{
    fac=1;  // Add this line here and remove from the end.
    rem=loop%10;
    while(rem>0)
    {
        fac=fac*rem;
        rem--;
    }
    strong_num=strong_num+fac;
    loop=loop/10;
}
```

As we need to find factorial of every single digit separately. For example for the number 145, we need to find factorial of 1,4 and 5. First after getting the factorial of 5 you need to reset `fac` variable to 1. which you were not doing and getting problem.

After change I am getting this output.

```
1
2
145
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I've aldeady figured out my mistake last night. But thanks for heloing me out.